# dotnet gitversion incorrect on main branch

Tags: .net, azure-devops, gitversion

I’ve set up git version on my dotnet project. When I pull a release branch (example: release/1.0.0) the calculated version number is correct (verison 1.0.0) but as soon as I merge this branch on hand, it calculates the number 0.1.0
I don’t understand where the problem is coming from.

I use Azure Devops

My GitVersion file :

```
assembly-versioning-scheme: MajorMinorPatch
assembly-file-versioning-scheme: MajorMinorPatch
mode: ContinuousDelivery
tag-prefix: '[vV]'
continuous-delivery-fallback-tag: ci
major-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(breaking|major)'
minor-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(feature|minor)'
patch-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(fix|patch)'
no-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(none|skip)'
legacy-semver-padding: 4
build-metadata-padding: 4
commits-since-version-source-padding: 4
tag-pre-release-weight: 60000
commit-message-incrementing: Enabled
branches:
  develop:
    mode: ContinuousDeployment
    tag: alpha
    increment: Minor
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
    track-merge-target: true
    regex: ^dev(elop)?(ment)?$
    source-branches: []
    tracks-release-branches: true
    is-release-branch: false
    is-mainline: false
    pre-release-weight: 0
  main:
    mode: ContinuousDelivery
    tag: ''
    increment: Patch
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: true
    track-merge-target: false
    regex: ^master$|^main$
    source-branches:
    - develop
    - release
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
    is-mainline: true
    pre-release-weight: 55000
  release:
    mode: ContinuousDeployment
    tag: beta
    increment: None
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: true
    track-merge-target: false
    regex: ^releases?[/-]
    source-branches:
    - develop
    - main
    - support
    - release
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: true
    is-mainline: false
    pre-release-weight: 30000
  feature:
    mode: ContinuousDeployment
    tag: useBranchName
    increment: Inherit
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
    track-merge-target: false
    regex: ^features?[/-]
    source-branches:
    - develop
    - main
    - release
    - feature
    - support
    - hotfix
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
    is-mainline: false
    pre-release-weight: 30000
  pull-request:
    mode: ContinuousDelivery
    tag: PullRequest
    increment: Inherit
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
    tag-number-pattern: '[/-](?<number>\d+)'
    track-merge-target: false
    regex: ^(pull|pull\-requests|pr)[/-]
    source-branches:
    - develop
    - main
    - release
    - feature
    - support
    - hotfix
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
    is-mainline: false
    pre-release-weight: 30000
  hotfix:
    mode: ContinuousDeployment
    tag: beta
    increment: Patch
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
    track-merge-target: false
    regex: ^hotfix(es)?[/-]
    source-branches:
    - develop
    - main
    - support
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
    is-mainline: false
    pre-release-weight: 30000
  support:
    mode: ContinuousDeployment
    tag: ''
    increment: Patch
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: true
    track-merge-target: false
    regex: ^support[/-]
    source-branches:
    - main
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
    is-mainline: true
    pre-release-weight: 55000
ignore:
  sha: []
commit-date-format: yyyy-MM-dd
merge-message-formats: {}
update-build-number: true
```